# Error while setting label to File's Owner

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch

UPDATED

I'm getting an error when I'm trying to set a label from my UICollectionViewCell to the File's Owner.

I was looking for similar questions, but the given solutions is not resolving my problem.

Here is my code:

1. CollectionCell Interface.

[image: CollectionCell Interface]

2. CollectionCell XIB (File's Owner).

[image: File's Owner Custom class]

[image: File's Owner outlets]

3. Label.

[image: Label outlets]

4. And finally and error that it throws

   [image: Error]

The error disappears when I removing the link between File's Owner and the label.

5. UPDATE. CollectionViewController code:
   [image: viewDidLoad]

[image]

Any suggestion? Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: let check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3088059/what-does-this-mean-nsunknownkeyexception-reason-this-class-is-not-key-v

Comment: Already tried. My CollectionView xib has the correct class.

Comment: Try to remove all references and add again

Comment: Following this answer and re-check your Xib https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3088059/what-does-this-mean-nsunknownkeyexception-reason-this-class-is-not-key-v/20132836#20132836

Comment: why you need to connect nameLabel with file owner?

Comment: @Scott.N thanks a lot. It's worked.

Comment: Do not post images of code or errors. Please [edit] your question and replace the images with the actual text of your code and the actual text of the stack trace. Images can't be searched, they are harder to read, and they can't be referenced when providing answers.

Comment: @rmaddy pasting a copy of stackstace it gives bad format so thats why I decided  to put an image.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear, I suggest you should show your code here:

[The crash location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQOH4.png)

Because your app crash here, and I guess maybe in that method you did't product the CollectionCell correctly.

**UPDATE**
Please check out your CollectionCell Xib here, and in identifier you should write your cell identifier:"CollectionCell"

[CollectionCell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P4U3z.jpg)

Comment: I'm updated the post adding the part of code of my CollectionViewController

Comment: Please look my update

Comment: This one is already set with CollectionCell

Comment: The error was on connecting the label to the File's Owner. Instead I should to link the label with my CollectionCell. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You are welcome! I did't catch core of this question......